# Identifying a movie based on Sci-fi (OS) Operating System. 2002-2008 probably

Tags: story-identification

I saw a what I believe to be a hacker movie once where there was an operating system and there was a hot girl in a bikini inside the operating system and she had a snake for some reason.  The graphics and editing in it were pretty good, higher quality than a tv show.

Also whenever he closed windows in the OS the windows caught Fire and dissipated, which I think is what inspired the plugin for compiz.

Can anyone tell me the name of the movie also I didn't hear any audio, but I was in a German airport when I saw it.  So it might be in German or the German thing might be a red herring.

edit: adding the extra info from the link Trish found at Dreamwalkers suggestion:

-Girl in bikini with snake

-Not a cartoon or animated

-She seemed to be the operating system in a computer (like inside the comp as a program)that this white guy with brown hair was using

-The shot was not exactly linear, meaning she would say something and they would skip to another angle making it look really cool.

- The guy was definitely in his teens to early twenties.
- The girl and snake were solid like you couldn't see through them.
- The guy was typing on a keyboard and the girl was saying stuff.
- I feel like he was in a warehouse or similar large empty building.
- It was like his monitor was 3d, not like the one in our computer. His seemed to open up into this room with this girl and snake.
- The girl was either sitting or laying down on her side.
- It would zoom in on a piece of the girl or the snake and then pan at an angle to the girls face or somewhere else.

Comment: bikini + snake = I'm a Slave 4U. :P

Comment: That said I did find someone else [asking about it](http://www.tv.com/science-fiction/help-me-find-what-was-on-tv-girl-in-bikini-w-snake/topic/107-2372343/msgs.html) but haven't located an answer yet.

Comment: Haha Trish, I'm the one who asked that in 2010 :)  It def has more details because I remembered it better at that time.  Also it's def not from earth final conflict, it was a higher quality production.

Comment: @Neil you should edit that other information into your question

Comment: One of the inspirations for several compiz animations is the 1995 film "Hackers". No idea if this is one of them, though - I don't have the movie handy.

Comment: @Omegacron I don't remember a "hot girl in a bikini" being part of an OS in Hackers. It's also quite a bit older than the 2002-2008 date range, though it's possible that part of the question isn't entirely correct.

Comment: You're not thinking of [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEseNgc_bJs) from TGWTDT, are you?

Comment: polynomial that's def not it, but good effort. It came out before TGWTDT.  Also in that one she is using Some kind of Apple operating system like OSX.In the one I'm searching for the key feature is that they had their own operating system and the bikini girl with the snake was inside giving that info.

Comment: Also 100% it's not from the 1995 hackers. The vibe I got from the scene was there was a more professional element going like he might have been part of a heist (purely speculation) also there might have been a lady and a black guy on the job with him. The bikini girl + snake was what was really characteristic I don't think the addition of the possible black guy and lady would help someone remember it more than the snake and girl though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it was "Weird science"?

Comment: Good effort Andrey Rybak, but it's 100% not weird science for multiple reasons.